# Check if variable is a recordset

Tags: asp-classic

It's been years since I don't work with classic asp, and I can't remember how to do this.

I am looping trough my session variables to print them in a textbox, but when it hit a recordset variable it returns me an error.

```vb
    Dim Item    
    Dim sessao

    For Each Item in Session.Contents
        If Item <> "Servidor" AND Not IsNull(Session.Contents(item)) THEN
            response.write(Session.Contents(item))
            response.write(item + "<br/>")
            'sessao = sessao + (Item + "&" + Session.Contents(item) + "@")
        end if
    next
```

So I need something like *if Item <> recordset then* to skip this situation

Comment: may I ask you why do you store recordset in a session variable? they are meant to store small data types, calling queries is not overly expensive.

Comment: This will happen with any Object based Session value. Try using `Not IsObject(Session.Contents(item)`.

Comment: Works great, thanks!

@meda, it's an old system and it's been rewritten in .NET now

Comment: yeah I see what you mean, well @Lankymart (lord of ASP) provided a good answer! `:)`

Comment: I don't see @Lankymart's (Lord of ASP) answer.  Wondering what his answer was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session values that contain objects will always cause an error if you try to `Response.Write` them to the page.

You can avoid this by checking whether the Session value contains an object using `IsObject()` function.

In your code something like

```vb
If Item <> "Servidor" And Not IsObject(Session.Contents(item)) Then
```

> **IMPORTANT:**
>
> As [meda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1880431/meda) points out it is expensive to store `ADODB.Recordset` objects inside session values. It's not recommended to do this if you can explain what it is you are trying to accomplish we might be able to provide a more viable solution.

Comment: The truth is that there is this asp/vb system and I am developing a new .NET one that need to be compatible with the asp one.

And since the session values cannot be shared between these two, I need to print them into a textbox to be able to get it in .NET system

Comment: @ChristopherFreyburg Right so you're just trying to work out what's in there and how to work with it. Understandable.

Comment: Session aren't sharable but you can develop some code that will take a [tag:asp-classic] session and convert it to a ASP.Net one. In effect it rebuilds the session object. It acts like a middleman between the two. See [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13067697/692942).

Comment: In fact I followed this [link](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20021207.asp) with some modifications, but thanks @Lankymart, you are very helpfull!