# How to transfer session variable from classic asp to asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp-classic

I am migrating from asp to asp.net application, where i need to pass the session variables from index.asp page to aspx page.There is a sample which demonstrates the session variable transfer.

[`Transfer Session Variables from Classic ASP to ASP.NET`](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20021207.asp)

here what i dont understand is that, where is the aspx page mentioned in asp page? is there a way to transfer to any aspx page wihtout mentioning in the index.asp page?

here is my code,

```
 dim sItem, i
  i= 0
  For each sItem in Session.Contents
    if i <> 0 then
      Response.Write("&")
    end if
    Response.Write(sItem & "=" & Server.UrlEncode(Session.Contents(sItem))) 
    i= i + 1
  next %>'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP to ASP.NET Session Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251137/asp-to-asp-net-session-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all ASP.NET is not an updated version of classic ASP.**

**Session in ASP.Net**
In ASP.NET, every Web page derives from the System.Web.UI.Page class. The Page class aggregates an instance of the HttpSession object for session data. In this example, a custom Page class called SessionPage is derived from the System.Web.UI.Page to offer all the same features as the Page class. The only difference with the derived page is that the default HttpSession is overridden with a custom session object.

**Session in Classic ASP**

The native ASP session can only store session data in memory. In order to store the session data to SQL Server, a custom Microsoft® Visual Basic® 6.0 COM object is written to manage the session state instead of using the native session object. This COM object will be instantiated in the beginning of each Web request and reload the session data from SQL Server. When the ASP script is finished, this object will be terminated and the session state will be persisted back to SQL Server.

**Implementation for Migration between Classic ASP to ASP.Net**

1.

**Steps to Set Up the Demo Program**

Create a new database called SessionDemoDb.
Create the SessState table (osql.exe –E –d SessionDemoDb –i Session.sql).
Create a new virtual directory called Demo.
Turn off ASP Session under the ASP configuration tab.
Copy the web.config, testPage.aspx, Global.asa, testPage.asp, and GlobalInclude.asp to the virtual directory.
Update the DSN string setting in the Global.asa and web.config. The session timeout setting is optional. The default is 20 minutes. 
Install the SessionUtility.dll into the Global Assembly Cache (gacutil /i SessionUtility.dll).
Expose the SessionUtility.dll as a COM object using the regasm.exe (regasm.exe SessionUtility.dll /tlb:SessionUtility.tlb).
Copy the SessionManager.dll to a local directory and use regsvr32.exe to register it (regsvr32 SessionManager.dll).
Grant the IUSR_ account to have read and execute access to the SessionMgr.dll.

**Steps to Run the Demo Program**

Start Microsoft® Internet Explorer.
Load the testPage.asp for classic ASP. The number "1" should appear in the Web page.
Click refresh on Internet Explorer to reload the page. The number should be incremented.
Change the URL to testPage.aspx for ASP.NET. The number should keep incrementing.
The same process can be repeated by starting the testPage.aspx page first.

2.

Whenever your application makes the jump, the page will be redirected to this newly created page which will create cookies for session variables which are essential for the user. These cookies will be then grabbed by ASP.NET. Using these cookies, create new session variables as required by the browser for ASP.NET.

More Information :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30723/Handle-session-variable-problems-between-classic-A