# Classic asp and asp.net mvc side by side

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

We want to convert a large Classic ASP application to ASP.NET MVC, using a phased development and implementation approach. The current application uses session  extensively. I have seen some old articles discussing how to share session state between the two architectures, but has anyone achieved this in more recent times, and if so, how?

Comment: Im not 100% sure on this but what I would do is create a test MVC app and throw in a classic ASP page initially to test compatibility. If all is OK, another problematic area I can think of are old to new URL structure clashes. If you know the two work together though then you can go from there.

Comment: Couple of approaches. `1.` store session state in a db and share with both. `2.` create a ASP.Net bridging page to pass session values through to Classic ASP. See [ASP to ASP.NET Session Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13067697/692942). This approach is bit cumbersome though. `3.` store values in cookies and retrieve *(if the domains match)*. `4.` Force a POST of the session variables.

Comment: I did something similar in Web Forms (not MVC but will be similar). See my blog post: http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/737/how-to-share-session-securely-between-classic-asp-and-asp-net/