# Share Session State Between ASP.NET and Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Great Article on this subject here: https://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/tip/Share-session-state-between-ASP-and-ASPNET-apps

Problem is, I cant get it to work without source code. The code snippets in the article show many errors in Visual Studios. The author, Dennis Hurst is unreachable, as it was written in 2004. Anybody out there have the actual Source code they can post ? Or maybe point me in the right direction ? My goal is to pull Classic ASP object data (Application) into ASP.Net code that shares the same folder. I have read that it might be possible using a COMM Wrapper, but that is way out of my skill level. This sounds like the best solution for my problem. Thank You in advance for your help.

```
// The constructor for this class takes a reference to the HttpContext and derives the URL it will need to send its requests to
    public ASPSessionVar(HttpContext oInContext)
    {
        oContext = oInContext;
        ASPSessionVarASP = "SessionVar.asp";
        /* We now build a System.Uri object to derive the correct
           URL to send the HTTP request to. oContext.Request.Url
           will contain a System.Uri object that represents
           this ASPXs URL.
        */
        System.Uri oURL = oContext.Request.Url;
        ASPSessionVarASP = oURL.Scheme + "://"
            + oURL.Host + ":" + oURL.Port.ToString()
            + ASPSessionVarASP;

    }


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    // The primary function for this example is called GetSessionVar. It does the majority of the work done by this application,
    // This includes creating a WebRequest, sending it off to the ASP page, and returning the response.


    // First get the Session Cookie
    string ASPCookieName = "";
    string ASPCookieValue = "";
 if (!GetSessionCookie
(out ASPCookieName, out ASPCookieValue))
 {
   return  "";
 }

 // Initialize the WebRequest.
 HttpWebRequest myRequest =
     (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create
     (ASPSessionVarASP + "?SessionVar=" + ASPSessionVar);
       myRequest.Headers.Add
     ("Cookie: " + ASPCookieName + "=" + ASPCookieValue);

 // Send the request and get a response
 HttpWebResponse myResponse =
   (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

    Stream receiveStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();

    System.Text.Encoding encode =
        System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

    StreamReader readStream =
        new StreamReader(receiveStream, encode);

    string sResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();

    // Do a bit of cleanup
    myResponse.Close();
 readStream.Close();
 return sResponse;
  }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// This function simply takes the Request that was passed by the client and extracts the ASP Session cookie from it. 
// This function is called by the GetSessionVar function to retrieve the ASPSession cookie.

private bool GetSessionCookie
  (out string ASPCookieName, out string ASPCookieValue)
   {
       int loop1;
       HttpCookie myCookie;     // Cookie variable

    ASPCookieName = "";
    ASPCookieValue = "";

    // Capture all cookie names into a string array.
    String[] CookieArray =
        oContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys;

    // Grab individual cookie objects by cookie name.
    for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < CookieArray.Length; loop1++)
    {
        myCookie =
          oContext.Request.Cookies[CookieArray[loop1]];
        if (myCookie.Name.StartsWith("ASPSESSION"))
        {
            ASPCookieName = myCookie.Name;
            ASPCookieValue = myCookie.Value;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//The ASPX page will instantiate an ASPSessionVar object, passing in the current Context to the construct or.
//The GetSessionVar function is then called, passing in the name of the ASP Session variable that is to be retrieved.


//Create an ASPSessionVar object,
//passing in the current context
SPI.WebUtilities.ASP.ASPSessionVar oASPSessionVar
  = new SPI.WebUtilities.ASP.ASPSessionVar(Context);
string sTemp = oASPSessionVar.GetSessionVar("FirstName");


// CLASSIC ASP CODE BELOW !!
//The ASP code for this example was placed in an ASP file called SessionVar.asp. 
// It performs two simple tasks. First, it ensures that the request is coming from the server that the ASP page is running on. 
// This ensures that the request is valid and coming ONLY from the Web server's IP address. 
// The ASP page then returns the session variable it was asked to provide

<%
  dim sT
  if Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") =
   Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR") then
   sT = Request("SessionVar")
   if trim(sT) <> "" then
     Response.Write Session(sT)
   end if
  end if
  %>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP to ASP.NET Session Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251137/asp-to-asp-net-session-variables)

Comment: Thank You, did not see the post wen I searched. Its seems to be what i am looking for !