# Getting the session data from ASP classic isn't working

Tags: asp.net, session, asp-classic

I am currently tasked with moving one of our older bits of software to a new server. The old server is running 2008 and the new server is on 2019. The code is a mixture of ASP and ASP.NET, both using VB. Unfortunately, I'm a C# developer and my VB knowledge is slight.

The main bit of the code is the older and is all in ASP and works fine on the new server. For a particular set of customers there is an add-on that is more recent and uses ASP.NET. For the new section of code to get the details of the logged in user it uses the code given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251137/asp-to-asp-net-session-variables) answer. Unfortunately it seems like it is this bit of code that is failing.

We have this bit of code in our site.master.vb

```
ctx1 = ctx.Request.Url.Scheme
ctx2 = ctx.Request.Url.Host
dom = ctx1 + "://" + ctx2

Dim ASPRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(New Uri(dom + "/arc/asp2netbridge.asp?sessVar=" + sessionValue))
ASPRequest.ContentType = "text/html"
ASPRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
If (ASPRequest.CookieContainer Is Nothing) Then
    ASPRequest.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
End If
```

The asp2netbridge.asp file is stored in the directory one up from the directory that contains the code and the directory structure looks the same on both servers. The contents of the as2netbridge file are the the same as in the example code linked above with the addition of some extra comments.

It then calls a Stored Procedure on our database with the customer ID from session that should return the customer details as XML, but instead we get a 'Root Element is missing' Error. If I change the Stored Procedure to hard code the customer ID in it, rather than as a parameter then it works as expected.

Is there anything that I need to install on our server to get the system working correctly? Or is there anything else I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: Classic ASP and asp.net are different technologies. Classic ASP (usually) uses a language called VBScript which is similar to, but not the same as VB.net which asp.net uses. (just as Javascript is not Java).  As far as session variables are concerned, variables set by classic asp pages can only be read by classic asp pages, and the same is true for .net pages,  whether they use C#, VB or whatever.  You appear to have a system in place for synchronising your session variables which I guess isn't working.

Comment: Could the problem be with the Stored Procedure?  It may be possible to rewrite it to  add the root element.

Comment: @John it's called a [Session Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13067697/692942) and I've used one in the past with no issue. I think they understand the difference between the technologies involved.

Comment: @user692942 My impression is that the OP has inherited someone else's code and is trying to make sense of it.  The "root element is missing" error makes me wonder if the session bridge is working and the issue is actually with the sql query which pulls the customer details. We need to see more code. If I were in his position I think the first thing I'd do would be to write a little standalone page in C# to see if it could read the session variables

Comment: @John It's more your first comment is completely incorrect. Whether they inherited or not, they seem to explained what is fairly well. That comment will just lead to them thinking they've understood it wrong.

Comment: @John I did inherit my code. The Stored procedure does work correctly if I hard code one of the customer codes, so I suspect the bridge isn't picking up the customer code correctly from the ASP side of things. The fact that it's worked fine fro years on our old servers indicates to me that I am missing something in out server setup

Comment: As I suggested, you could add a simple .aspx page containing `<%=Session["YourVariableName"]%>` . (Square brackets for C#, round ones for VB). That would establish for certain whether the bridge was synchronising your sessions correctly.  Another thing which occurs.  Is `dom` giving you the correct path to your bridge?  It's often something really simple, eg your new server has a redirect to https: rule in place but your script is still trying to access the http: location

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion John. I did get excited about the http to https redirect as that appeared to be happening, but it wasn't, it was just Chrome redirecting for me. I seem to have got somewhere though. The original code in the linked question has a check between the servervariables "LOCAL_ADDR" and "REMOTE_ADDR", if I comment that check out then it works. I will follow this lead and see where it goes.